# Mix twig templating and text in bolt cms

Tags: templates, twig, bolt-cms

I came to a point where I wanted to display some of my custom contenttype in a html field in bolt. I have a page where I'm editing the content and within the content I'd like to display some of my contenttype's attributes. 
Can I somehow display data using the template engine like `{ mycontenttype.title }`, can I include some `partials` in a html field or do I have to write my own template and have to deal with the fact I can't put my own contenttype inbetween the normal text? 
My attempt so far was to try using the templateing style, which didn't work out and I didn't find a trace yet on how to configure it (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to allow [twig tags on your field](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/fields/html#options) in your `contenttypes.yml` file by adding: `allowtwig: true` to your html field definition.